# ArcGIS Pro Arcade Expression - Validation Rule

Tags: expression, arcade

I am trying to create a validation rule that identifies duplicates within the column ID. Can anyone see where is the problem? I am getting all the features as returns which is not the intention with the code below:

```
var tbl = FeaturesetbyName($datastore, "IDs", ["ID"], false);
var id = $feature.ID
var query = `ID = ${id}`;
var filID = Filter(tbl, query);
var countID = Count(filID);
function isDup(value){
    if (value > 1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
isDup(countID)
```

Comment: A validation rule isn't going to filter records, it is going to highlight records that violate the condition.  Are you saying the validation status for all the records is the same while you expect some of them to say there is an error?

Comment: @bixb0012 Yea, exactly that. Also, while the expression is verified as valid in the expression builder window. The error pops up after trying to save it.

Comment: Now you state there is an error, which hasn't been mentioned before.  If there is an error, update your question with the specifics of the error.  If you are getting an error, then the rule isn't being processed.